# JSON to xml conversion using jQuery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Javascript and jQuery and I want to create a function to convert JSON to XML. I searched through the internet and the only one I got is http://code.google.com/p/x2js/

Below is the function I wrote and it does not work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src="x2js-v1.1.5/xml2json.min.js"></script>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                $(window).load(function(){
                    var json = null;
                    var x2js=newX2JS();
                        $.ajax({
                        'async': false,
                        'global': false,
                        'url': "sample.json",
                        'dataType': "json",
                        'success': function (data) {
                            json = data;
                        }
                        });

                    function convertJsonToXml(){
                        var xmlDOM=x2js.json2xml(json);}

    });
            </script>
        </head>

    </html>
```

The json file I want to read is "sample.json". It is at the same directory as the html file.

Someone please help me to make this work.

This is the error I'm having in the console

> TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function jquery-git.js:9217:8
>   The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is trying to use the Ajax `load` method instead of binding a load event handler. The function you are passing isn't a URL string so it errors.

You want:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
```

instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try if this works. In this way you will be able to locate the problem.

```
$(window).load(function(){
       var json = {'a': 'b'};
       var x2js=new X2JS().json2xml(json);
}
```